# Is it permissible for a Muslim man to marry a Sikh woman?

Tags: nikah, other-religions

I have been with a girl and I am intending to marry her. The only thing is that she is from Sikh religion. It is stated that a Muslim can only marry among the people of the book (Torah, Bible and Qur'an of course). Because they believe in One God. Sikhism came after Islam so there wasn't any restrictions on the marriage between a Sikh and Muslim. They believe in one god also. I will raise my children Muslims, but I want to know if I will be doing a sin by marrying her.

Comment: AFAIK, Sikhs are prohibited from consuming halal meat. and *I will raise my children Muslims* is barely possible to accomplish. Do not stick to that hope.

Comment: Also note that, although Sikhs are not polytheists or idolaters, they are not marriageable. A lot of the newly emerged religion were influenced by or derived from Islam, eg: Sikhism, Druze, Bahai etc, and hence, they resemble Islam in terms of concept of God. But they are not believers. Sikhs may believe in one God but they do not believe in our prophets.

Comment: They also donot believe in Judgement day. Just bcoz Sikhism came after Islam doesn't mean there wasn't any restrictions on the marriage between a Sikh and Muslim. If marriage with other monotheistic religions were possible, marriage with zoroastrians would also have been possible, which is not the case. *[zoro\*.s are monotheists: http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/religions/zoroastrian/ataglance/glance.shtml ]*

Comment: Just for info: Even in Sikh Religion marrying a Muslim lead to religious punishment of excommunication called Patit. Famous Maharaja Ranjit Singh was punished by Akali Phoola Singh Nihang for marrying with Muslim Girl. If Sikhs properly follow their rules, then Muslims need not to think on this question. Both would be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Non-Muslims totally are of two kinds:

1. The first one consists of People of the Book
2. the second one consists of Not People of the Book.

**In accordance with the view of all Shiite  jurists, a Moslem man cannot get married (neither temporarily nor permanently) to a non-Moslem woman who isn't of the People of the Book**

The significant point is that you ought to pay attention if it (Sikh) is really considered as "people of the book", if not, as a rule you cannot Marry her and it could be considered as a big sin.

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa913)

Answer (score 0):

No. See this, please:

> Allah says (interpretation of the meaning): “And do not marry Al- Mushrikaat (idolatresses) till they believe (worship Allaah Alone). And indeed a slave woman who believes is better than a (free) Mushrikah (idolatress), even though she pleases you. And give not (your daughters) in marriage to Al‑Mushrikoon till they believe (in Allaah Alone) and verily, a believing slave is better than a (free) Mushrik (idolater), even though he pleases you. Those (Al-Mushrikoon) invite you to the Fire, but Allaah invites (you) to Paradise and forgiveness by His Leave, and makes His Ayaat (proofs, evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) clear to mankind that they may remember” [[al-Baqarah 2:221](http://quran.com/2/221)]

Comment: muslims cannot marry sikhs . they are *montheistic-non-believes*, to be concise